# For constant expressions, why can't I use a use a pointer-type object, as standards says?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, constant-expression

I was trying to figure out the restrictions of `constexpr` in cpp11/14. There are some usage requirements I found in CPP14-5.19-4:

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression
> whose value refers to an object with static storage duration or to a
> function, or a prvalue core constant expression whose value is an
> object where, for that object and its subobjects:
>
> - ...
> - if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains **the address of another object with static storage duration**, the address past
>   the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or
>   **a null pointer value**.

I've run some tests(code shown below) for expressions that involves address-of operator `&`, in order to ensure the correctness of the standards' statements quoted above.

Simply put, I tried to take the address of a global *int* variable `global_var`, which is an object with *static storage duration*(if I was not thinking wrong), everything works just as standards points out. But, what confused me is that, when I tried to assign another pointer-type object(`global_var_addr1` in code), which stored the address of the same object `global_var`, the program won't compile. And GCC says:

> error: the value of ‘global_var_addr1’ is not usable in a constant expression
> note: ‘global_var_addr1’ was not declared ‘constexpr’

, while Clang-Tidy says:

> error: constexpr variable 'x2' must be initialized by a constant expression [clang-diagnostic-error]
> note: read of non-constexpr variable 'global_var_addr1' is not allowed in a constant expression

and I don't know why, is there anything I missed?

##### So my question is:

**1. Why, in a *constant expression*, I cannot use a pointer-type object which contains the address of an object with static storage duration, as standards says?**
**2. Why everything goes different in the same context as (1), when the object is `auto` specified?**

Any advices would be welcomed, thanks in advance!

---

Code:

```cpp
const int global_var_c = 123;
int global_var = 123;
const void *global_var_addr1 = &global_var;
const void *global_var_addr2 = nullptr;
auto global_var_addr3 = nullptr;

auto  main() -> int
{
    constexpr const int x00 = global_var_c;           // OK
    constexpr const void *x0 = &global_var;           // OK

    // Operate on the object of pointer type
    constexpr const void *x1 = &global_var_addr1;      // OK
    constexpr const void *x2 = global_var_addr1;       // ERROR: read of non-constexpr variable 'global_var_addr1'...

    // Operate on nullptr
    constexpr const void *x3 = &global_var_addr2;     // OK
    constexpr const void *x4 = global_var_addr2;      // ERROR: read of non-constexpr variable 'global_var_addr2'...

    // Operate on nullptr (with type deduction)
    constexpr const void *x5 = global_var_addr3;      // OK
    constexpr const void *x6 = &global_var_addr3;     // OK
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both

```
constexpr const void *x2 = global_var_addr1;
```

and

```
constexpr const void *x4 = global_var_addr2;
```

a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens from the variable `global_var_addr1`/`global_var_addr2` glvalue to the pointer value they hold. Such a conversion is only allowed if the variable's lifetime began during the evaluation of the constant expression (not the case here) or if it is *usable in constant expressions*, meaning that it is `constexpr` (not the case here) or initialized by a constant expression (is the case here) *and* of reference or `const`-qualified integral/enumeration type (not the case here).

Therefore the initializers are not constant expressions.

---

This is different in the case of

```
constexpr const int x00 = global_var_c;
```

since `global_var_c` is of `const`-qualified integral type.

---

I am not exactly sure about

```
constexpr const void *x5 = global_var_addr3;      // OK
```

Intuitively it should work, because the type of `nullptr` and consequently the deduced type of `global_var_addr3` is `std::nullptr_t` which doesn't need to carry any state, so that a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion wouldn't be necessary. Whether the standard actually guarantees that, I am not sure at the moment.

Reading the current wording (post-C++20 draft), [conv.ptr] specifies only conversion of a null pointer constant (i.e. a *prvalue* of `std::nullptr_t`) to another pointer type and [conv.lval] specifically states how the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `std::nullptr_t` produces a null pointer constant. [conv.lval] also clarifies in a note that this conversion doesn't access memory, but I don't think that makes it not a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion given that it still written under that heading.

So it seems to me that strictly reading the standard

```
constexpr const void *x5 = global_var_addr3;      // OK
```

should be ill-formed (whether `global_var_addr3` is `const`-qualified or not).

[Here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41785) is an open clang bug for this. There seems to be a link to come internal discussion by the standards committee, which I cannot access.

---

In any case, the `auto` placeholder doesn't matter. You could have written `std::nullptr_t` for it instead directly.

All of these are requirements for being a *core constant expression*, which is a prerequisite to the requirements you mention in your question.

Comment: _No lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is required to copy that type_ Which paragraph says this?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Right, I am not actually sure it says that anywhere. I rewrote the part of the answer until I find something definitive.

Comment: Clang verstion 8.0.1 and earlier doesn't accept the `nullptr_t`-case https://godbolt.org/z/dPGE6qM1q

Comment: We know [conv.lval] special cases `std::nullptr_t` (an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object with type *cv* `std::nullptr_t` results in a null pointer constant), but [expr.const] defining a core constant expression doesn't mention `std::nullptr_t`, and if `constexpr const void *x5 = global_var_add3` does do an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (which I suspect it does), it is not a constant expression.

Comment: @Artyer Yes, this would also be my understanding. I have updated the answer

Comment: @LanguageLawyer There is an open regression bug filed in LLVM's bug tracker for that change. I have updated my answer with how I see it after reading the standard again.

Comment: @user17732522 "*Such a conversion is only allowed if ... or initialized by a constant expression (is the case here)*" Can I have some standards reference related to this constraint?

Comment: @absuu [\[expr.const\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const) in the post-C++20 draft. (5.8.1) is the _usable in constant expressions_ requirement on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in core constant expressions, (4) defines _usable in a constant expression_ for variables as _constant initialized_ (initialized by a constant expression) and _potentially constant_ plus some modules related requirements. (2) gives the exact definition of _constant initialized_ and (3) defines _potentially constant_ with the type requirement in the absence of `constexpr`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for the precise references! I'm kind of new to cpp and carefully read through what you provided. So, is it rigorous to say that :  in my example, `global_var_addr1` is *potentially-constant* because its intializer `&global_var` is a constant expression. But since I haven't specified `global_var_addr1` as an expression that is *usable-in-constant-expression*, by explicit specifier `constexpr`, it remains *potentially-constant* property, along with which the *lvalue-to-rvalue conv* happened on it cannot result in an constant expression, according to *[expr.const]-5.81* ?

Comment: @absuu `global_var_addr1` is _constant-initialized_ for the reason you gave, but not _potentially-constant_ because it is not `constexpr`, not a reference and not a `const`-qualified integral or enumeration type. Adding `constexpr` to `global_var_addr1` would satisfy this additional condition and both together make it _usable-in-constant-expressions_. Without the full _usable-in-constant-expression_ requirement applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to it is not allowed in a constant expression.

Comment: @absuu Practically speaking, it is easier to remember that you cannot use the value of any variable not marked `constexpr` in a constant expression. As we discussed there are some exceptions, but these are corner cases which you probably don't want to rely on.

Comment: @user17732522  Thanks for the pratically advice again! One thing that I'm still not much sure is that, accoding to the reference *[expr.const]-11* and *[expr.const]-11.2*, can I view `x0` as *a glvalue core constant expression*, and `&global_var` as *a prvalue core constant expression*?

Comment: @absuu Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: @user17732522 Deeply appreciate for your kindly patience, and actually don't know how to express my appreciation more than an acceptance, just...THANK YOU again!

Answer (score 1):

The variable declared here is clearly not `constexpr` (nor even `const`):

```
const void *global_var_addr1 = &global_var;
```

And you can't use non-constexpr values to initialize constexpr values.  So it's no surprise this fails to compile:

```
constexpr const void *x2 = global_var_addr1; // ERROR: read of non-constexpr
```

The address of a non-constexpr value can be used in cases like you've shown, however, but the value stored in a variable and the address of a variable are not the same thing.